# Eclipse doesn't show breakpoints in "Problem_view"

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints

I think I have turned off some option in Preferences and now I cannot find it. I'd like to see all breakpoints in my application. Can You help me?

Comment: Which eclipse version ?

Comment: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Kepler Release
Build id: 20130614-0229. I already discovered selfstanding view "Breakpoints" in debug layout, but earlier this information were in "Problem" view at compilation time.

Comment: Could it be possible that you minimized the Debugging window ? If so, you should be able to maximize it via a button (on Luna, on the left)

Comment: The breakpoints were visible in Problem view, withou debugging. Problems are grouped into Java compiler problems, Javascript, XML, Maven, ToDo etc. One group was called Breakpoints. I turned off some problems in Preferences->Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings, Javascript->Validator, and some other places. Now I cannot turn on  the Breakpoints back.

Comment: On Luna, you can turn them back via Window/OpenView/OtherView/BreakPoint (or `alt-shift-Q Q`). I don't have a Kepler available, so could you please tell me if this work ?

Comment: Yes, I can open "Breakpoints" view as mentioned above, but I cannot force Eclipse to display it in "Problems" view. My question isn't how to clear breakpoints, but how to configure "Problems" view to show them.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one:

Go to **Window > Customize Perspective** 
Tick checkbox **Skip All Breakpoints** under **Debug** from **Tool Bar Visibility** as shown

It works for me perfectly